# How can I stop IDisposable invokes while render the page in blazor server-side?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor

Here is my code:

```
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits
@inject CircuitHandler circuitHandler
@implements IDisposable

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

@code{
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("123");//do something
        }
    }
    #region//circuitHandler
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        // Subscribe to the event handler
        (circuitHandler as CircuitHandlerService).CircuitsChanged +=
             HandleCircuitsChanged;

    }


    public void HandleCircuitsChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("123");//do something
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        (circuitHandler as CircuitHandlerService).CircuitsChanged -=
          HandleCircuitsChanged;

    }
    #endregion
}
```

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits;
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BlazorApp2
{
    public class CircuitHandlerService : CircuitHandler
    {
        public ConcurrentDictionary<string, Circuit> Circuits
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public event EventHandler CircuitsChanged;

        protected virtual void OnCircuitsChanged()
             => CircuitsChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);

        public CircuitHandlerService()
        {
            Circuits = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Circuit>();
        }

        public override Task OnCircuitOpenedAsync(Circuit circuit,
                             CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Circuits[circuit.Id] = circuit;
            //OnCircuitsChanged();
            return base.OnCircuitOpenedAsync(circuit,
                                  cancellationToken);
        }

        public override Task OnCircuitClosedAsync(Circuit circuit,
                  CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Circuit circuitRemoved;
            Circuits.TryRemove(circuit.Id, out circuitRemoved);
            OnCircuitsChanged();
            return base.OnCircuitClosedAsync(circuit,
                              cancellationToken);
        }

        public override Task OnConnectionDownAsync(Circuit circuit,
                              CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return base.OnConnectionDownAsync(circuit,
                             cancellationToken);
        }

        public override Task OnConnectionUpAsync(Circuit circuit,
                            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return base.OnConnectionUpAsync(circuit, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
}
```

I need the `CircuitHandler` to get to know whether the page is closed.

Now I met a strange problem. When the page is loaded, the `IDisposable` always invoke even the page is not closed.

What's more, there are several codes in `OnAfterRenderAsync`. When the `IDisposable` invokes, the codes in `OnAfterRenderAsync` which not runs finished will suddenly break without any error.

Someone told me to set the

```
@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<App>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered))
```

in `_Host.cshtml` to

```
@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<App>(RenderMode.Server))
```

can solve this.
I tried, but the problem still here.
How can I solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the code snippet below is exactly like yours, and it works for me perfectly fine. The Dispose method is called only when a Circuit is closed. I'll post below the entire code I use, copy and run it, then I'll try to help with other issues you have.

```
<app>
        @(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<App>(RenderMode.Server))
 </app>
```

Note: I'm posting here entire files' content. You'll have to adjust the namespaces of my app with yours.

### Code for CircuitHandlerService.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits;
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace BlazorCircuitHandler.Services
{
public class CircuitHandlerService : CircuitHandler 
{
    public ConcurrentDictionary<string, Circuit> Circuits { get; set; }
    public event EventHandler CircuitsChanged;

    protected virtual void OnCircuitsChanged()
    => CircuitsChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);

    public CircuitHandlerService()
    {
        Circuits = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Circuit>();
    }

    public override Task OnCircuitOpenedAsync(Circuit circuit, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Circuits[circuit.Id] = circuit;
        OnCircuitsChanged();
        return base.OnCircuitOpenedAsync(circuit, cancellationToken);
    }

    public override Task OnCircuitClosedAsync(Circuit circuit, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        Circuit circuitRemoved;
        Circuits.TryRemove(circuit.Id, out circuitRemoved);
        OnCircuitsChanged();
        return base.OnCircuitClosedAsync(circuit, cancellationToken);
    }

    public override Task OnConnectionDownAsync(Circuit circuit, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        return base.OnConnectionDownAsync(circuit, cancellationToken);
    }

    public override Task OnConnectionUpAsync(Circuit circuit, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return base.OnConnectionUpAsync(circuit, cancellationToken);
    }

 }
}
```

### Code for Index.razor

```
@page "/"

@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits
@using BlazorCircuitHandler.Services

@inject CircuitHandler circuitHandler
@implements IDisposable


<p>
    Number of Circuits: @((circuitHandler as 
    BlazorCircuitHandler.Services.CircuitHandlerService).Circuits.Count)
   <ul>
     @foreach (var circuit in (circuitHandler as 
            BlazorCircuitHandler.Services.CircuitHandlerService).Circuits)
     {
        <li>@circuit.Key</li>
     }
  </ul>
</p>

@code {

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    (circuitHandler as CircuitHandlerService).CircuitsChanged += 
                   HandleCircuitsChanged;

}

public void Dispose()
{

    (circuitHandler as CircuitHandlerService).CircuitsChanged -= 
              HandleCircuitsChanged;

}

public void HandleCircuitsChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged());
}
}
```

### Also Startup class

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Removed for brevity....

        services.AddSingleton<CircuitHandler>(new CircuitHandlerService());
    }
```

### And of course _Host.cshtml

```
<app>
        @(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<App>(RenderMode.Server))
</app>
```

Please, don't fail to report ...

Comment: Finally, I found the problem. Actually, your way exactly works. The problem is I used the Visual Studio Code to debug the program on the server computer. There is a bug in my code while Visual Studio Code never reports it until I used a try&catch around it. When the program running into the code line of the bug, the page crashes and invokes the dispose method automatically.

Comment: Anyway, I will accept your answer for it may help any other people who met IDisposable invokes when page loaded.

Comment: What's more, I wonder why the IDisposable invokes when the page loaded in RenderMode.ServerPrerendered